# Nodejs steady memory usage increase

Tags: node.js, rest, memory, memory-leaks, puppeteer

I try to run my Node.js program overnight, but when I come back in the morning, I have an error that says:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[27916:0000018154883920] 81701561 ms: Scavenge 2018.5 (2066.4) -> 2003.2 (2066.4) MB, 11.4 / 
0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.325, current mu = 0.265) allocation failure
[27916:0000018154883920] 81701732 ms: Scavenge 2018.8 (2066.4) -> 2003.3 (2067.2) MB, 9.7 / 
0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.325, current mu = 0.265) allocation failure


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF6C2D377DD]
1: StubFrame [pc: 00007FF6C2CBDC81]
Security context: 0x014609f408d1 <JSObject>
2: parseDecimal(aka parseDecimal) [0000029364B9A329] [C:\Users\MelondO\valr\node_modules\decimal.js\decimal.js:~3517] [pc=0000035F2AE3294F](this=0x01efd30004b1 <undefined>,0x0364b324cf01 <Decimal map = 0000007D5C082A09>,0x0397fa998541 <String[#5]: 37520>)
3: new Decimal [000000B8CB69AB81] [C:\Users\MelondO\va...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6C212470F napi_wrap+113583
 2: 00007FF6C20CF7D6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+66646
 3: 00007FF6C20D05D6 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+70230
 4: 00007FF6C28E42EE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF6C28CC3C1 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF6C279890C v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF6C27A3B40 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF6C27A0664 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF6C2795E63 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF6C27944D4 v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap+2452
11: 00007FF6C27B56DD v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+61
12: 00007FF6C251BF61 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterator::operator=+1665
13: 00007FF6C2D377DD v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546637
14: 00007FF6C2CBDC81 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+48113
15: 0000035F2AE3294F
```

I am subscribed to 4 websockets, do more than 100 REST requests per second and scrape 2 pages with puppeteer. I observe a steady increase in the memory required by the Node.exe process every second. I though Node was the kind of language where you don't think about these things (garbage collector)? Is this a common occurence? I am using node 16 and Windows 10. Maybe this is problematic (see below)?

```
function connect(){
    let WS = new WebSocket("wss://path");
    WS.on("close", () => {
        WS = null;
        setImmediate(connect);
   })
}
```

This is the puppeteer code:

```
let page;
let dec;

async function puppeteerSetup(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
    page = (await browser.pages())[0];
}


async function scrape(){
    while(true){
        try{
            const url = "https://example.com/";
            if((await page.url()) === url){
                await page.reload();
            } else {
                await page.goto(url);
            }
            dec = new Decimal(await page.evaluate(() => {
                return document.getElementsByClassName("converter-title-amount")[0].innerHTML;
            }));
            compute();
        } catch (err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    } 
}

async function start(){
    await puppeteerSetup();
    scrape();
}

start();
```

Comment: Saw this on github issues might help might not (https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/issues/292#issuecomment-446729835)

Comment: Increasing usable memory just postpone the inevitable error I think.It would be nice to fix the issue at its root. Is there anything about what I am doing that could allocate memory that is never released?

Comment: We would have to see your code to have any idea what the problem could be.  There are also hundreds of other posts here about the process of tracking down memory leaks.  Normally nodejs is garbage collected just fine and you don't have to worry about accumulating memory, but there are bad things you can do to cause problems, particularly when using things like puppeteer that involve outside code.  My first wild guess would be that you aren't cleaning up scraped web pages properly in puppeteer..

Comment: I reload a page every few seconds, I re-use always the same page. Anything I should be aware of?

Comment: I posted a bit of code I think is suspicious, what do you think? Does it create an infinite recursion?

Comment: You're not showing any of the interesting code.  I already told you that I suspected your puppeteer code.  All you showed here was code that reconnects a websocket.  That does not create infinite recursion by itself as `setImmediate()` waits for the stack to clear before calling the function you pass it.

Comment: Here I got interesting puppeteer code. This is an eternal loop to evaluate the value of dec continuously. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This will need classic memory leak tracking.  Probably you will want to generate a heap snapshot every N iterations of your loop and then analyze those snapshots to try to see what data is accumulating (one possibility is browser history).   It's also possible that you should only use a browser instance for a certain number of page reloads (maybe 1000) before releasing it and starting with a new one so that they don't, by themselves, accumulate memory usage.

Comment: Do you know if the chromium process itself is getting super large or if it's just the nodejs process that is getting large?

Comment: This is likely not the source of your issue, but if you get an error and hit your `catch`, you immediately try again.  That can lead to an avalanche-type failure where an overloaded system gets slow and generates errors and now you start hammering it even harder causing even more errors.  When you get an error, you should insert a delay before trying again so you aren't hammering an already failing server.  Consecutive failures should even back off to delay longer (to try to allow system to recover).

Comment: Apparently, this is a regular situation: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5893
Making new browsers indeed fix the issue, making incognito pages do not. Thank you! The chromium processes were getting big also,. up to 500M. Ill be sure to make my system more fault tolerant with your suggestion!

Comment: What's `compute()`? Is there any chance this is orphaning a reference to your `Decimal` object? I'm not sure I understand why you're using a global here rather than a parameter. Habits like that are more likely to cause memory leaks. Voting to close as lacking a [mcve].

Comment: I use my Decimal object in computations triggered by events, which sometimes happen in parallel. compute() is called by many different events (each time an input of the computation is modified). It seemed convenient to have global variables for each input modified by each event. What design would you go for? And you can probably reproduce the bug by taking my puppeteer code, going on any webpage and reloading in a loop.

Comment: And now I have the problem of zombie chromiums :,)

Comment: If this is not a  `productive` project I suggest to launch `puppeteer` in a `suprocess` and simply relaunching it every x minutes. I have a webscraper which we are using in our company for showing some data on a dashboard. I had similar problems and this was a not very time consuming but still an acceptable fix.